# failed to resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-add:11.6.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, admob

I'm trying to integrate Mobile Ads SDK on my personal app. however, I'm having `failed to resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-add:11.6.0` error when syncing module:app Gradle. Please help me how to solve this issue.[image]

Comment: Simply click install repo and sync and it will be fixed

Comment: Thank you Brother!

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried adding this to your build.gradle options?

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: this answer solved my issue. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

Look at SDK Manager > SDK Tools if Google Play Services are installed in the newest version. If they're installed, try

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.+'
```

instead of

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'
```

Comment: Completely wrong