# How to solve ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:11.6.0 in Android project?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

In my Android project, I have following configuration in my **app level gradle file**-

**build.gradle(module:app)**

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.XXX"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "6.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id               : 'my app id',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.6'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'


}
```

And here's the configuration of my project level gradle file-

**build.gradle(module:project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And inside my **Manifest.xml** file I have set the follwoing lines in **application** tag-

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

My code used to work perfectly before today. But today when I opened my project it showing the following error while gradle building-

> ERROR: Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:11.6.0 Show in
>   Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:11.6.0 Show in
>   Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app

I have tried the following suggestions but didn't work for me-
[failed to resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-add:11.6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230692/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-add11-6-0)

So, i need a solution to solve this issue to make my **gradle** build successful and use the mentioned dependencies of **firebase**.

Comment: try to use a new versions of these dependencies, that may solve the problem

Comment: I did update but it is showing the following error-

Error: Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:13:5-234:19 to override. app main manifest (this file), line 21

Answer (score 2):

add this in build.gradle (:app)

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your repositories blocks, try putting google() before jcenter().

Example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}
```

becomes:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```